# Using MEF with DI in a WebApi application

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, mef

I'm planning on using MEF to implement a plugin architecture for my import plugins. These plugins will import various data into the db (eg. customers, addresses, products, etc).

The import plugin class looks like this:

```
public interface IImportPlugin
{
    string Name { get; }
    void Import();
}

[Export(typeof(IImportPlugin))]
public class ImportCustomers : IImportPlugin
{
    private readonly ICustomerService customerService;

    public string Name
    {
        get { this.GetType().Name; }
    }

    public ImportCustomers(ICustomerService _customerService) 
    {
        customerService = _customerService;
    }

    public void Import() {}
}
```

I then have a controller, which first gets all import plugins as follows:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetImportPlugins()
{
    var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();

    catalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "bin")));

    var directoryCatalog = new DirectoryCatalog(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Plugins"));
    catalog.Catalogs.Add(directoryCatalog);

    var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
    container.ComposeParts();

    var list = container.GetExportedValues<IImportPlugin>().Select(x => x.Name);
    return Ok(list);
}
```

The import plugin needs to reference my `Services` assembly because this is where the BL takes place. I register my services in the main WebApi project with Autofac as follows:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies)
  .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
  .AsImplementedInterfaces()
  .InstancePerRequest();
```

Is it possible to pass different services to different import plugins?

For example, if I'm importing products I need to pass the `ProductService`, and if I'm importing customers I might need to pass `CustomerService` and `AddressService`.

How can I inject these services inside the plugins (through their constructors just like one would do in a controller)?

Comment: Can't you register modules in your plugins? For example, in ninject you can specify NinjectModule in which you register your plugin depenedncies. Then in your main modules you just register all modules in plugin folder, and all your BL interfaces implementations will be available inside plugins.

Answer (score 0):

For plugin-like architecture, you need three things:

- Contracts (basicaly assembly containing only interfaces and simple
  objects withouth BL). This will be used as API for your plugins. Also, here you can specify IImportPlugin interface.
- Module which responsibily will be loading plugin modules from some folder, or from somewhere else.
- Module in each plugin you create, to register your plugin as IImportPlugin inside DI container.

You can register your plugin modules like this in loop:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyModules(/*plugin 'Assembly' goes here*/);
```

In your plugin assembly, in specific module, you specify only your plugin registration:

```
public class MyPluginModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Register<ImportCustomers>().As<IImportPlugin>();
    }
}
```

Then in plugin implementation **ImportCustomer** you can use everything from **Contract** assembly (for example your **ICustomerService** interface). And if your system registered dependecies for your plugin - it will succesfuly load into DI container.

Comment: I don't want to register plugins using DI because they have to be known beforehand and it the defeats the purpose of a plugin architecture using MEF.